# Unknown column 'sitename' in 'where clause'

Tags: php, database

```
public function getSiteValues($value) {
    $this->db->select(
        'site', 
        'id, option_name, option_value', 
        NULL, 
        'option_name=' . $value
    ); // database, what to take, where value 
    $res = $this->db->getResult();

    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($res);
    echo '</pre>';
}
```

In this case I would like to put for example:

```
getSiteValues('sitename')
```

and so that this would return the value of `sitename` row and from `option_value` column, but it keep giving me error such as

```
[0] => Unknown column 'sitename' in 'where clause'
```

What can I do to fix this?

PS. I have tried to look at other solutions but they have keep giving me wrong solutions. I have tried most of them. btw I am using this crud library - https://github.com/rorystandley/MySQL-CRUD-PHP-OOP for db connections

Comment: You need to put escaping strings around `$value`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've to escape the `$value`

```
public function getSiteValues($value) {
    $this->db->select(
        'site', 
        'id, option_name, option_value', 
        NULL, 
        'option_name="' . $value . '"'
    ); // database, what to take, where value 
    $res = $this->db->getResult();

    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($res);
    echo '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[0] => Unknown column 'sitename' in 'where clause'
```

This kind of error occurs due to the column name being incorrect. You have to check the table columns, or use the mysql escape character for `$value`.

something like, `mysql_real_escape_string($value)`